# Should I accept an answer to a homebrew-review question if I think I might be biased?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, homebrew, accepted-answer

Suppose I ask a [homebrew-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-review) question, and I receive at least one answer that, though acceptable with respect to the site rules, I don't particularly like. (Maybe I feel they didn't read my post carefully enough or that they were overly critical of something creative I was trying out—the reason isn't really important, the point is that I'm likely to feel justified in my dislike of such a post whether I really am justified or I'm taking good criticism too personally.)

It goes without saying that we all try as hard as possible to be objective on this site, but that's an unrealistic expectation when people are posting their own creations for others to review in public.

Should I accept an answer to a such a question if I suspect that I might be biased against one or more of the answers? If so, how should I decide which answer to accept?

Comment: When you say "choose an answer", I assume you're referring to choosing which answer to mark as your accepted answer?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are free to accept any answer that you like, even when it has 20 downvotes.

From [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
> statement indicating that the question has now been answered
> perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that
> worked for them personally. Not every user comes back to accept an
> answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer
> even if a newer, better answer comes along later.

The first paragraph of the article indicates that you should choose a good answer, but you are the arbiter of what you understand as a good answer to your question, even when you feel unqualified. Please use your best judgement.

Comment: Thanks! I figured there was probably already a policy adjacent to this. (This seems to answer it, but I'll wait a couple days before accepting in case there are differing views out there.)